# How do I display the value of a session variable in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session-cookies

First I don't know if I'm declaring a session variable correctly. Also, I put it in the application controller, because I know it will run. If there is a better place to put this, then please let me know. The desired outcome is a user selects the team they want all their work to save to during the session. Then when objects are saved they use the session variable :current_team instead of :current_user. By default on creation a team will be created for each new user. That is why I'm querying for the first team for each user. During the session I plan for the user to select the team they are working/contributing for and the selection persist until they change it.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_team

  def set_current_team
    return unless session[:current_team]
    session[:current_team] = Team.first.where(user_id: current_user).id
  end


end
```

index.html.erb

```
<p><%= session[:current_team] %></p>
```

output

```
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/dev/.rbenv/versions/2.5.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_navigation.html.erb (2.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 172ms (Views: 168.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

My models are Team, User, and a join table Team_member. 
team_member.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :role
end
```

team.rb

```
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
  has_many :roles, through: :team_members
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume one user can be part of multiple teams and (obviously) one team has many users, your relation would be roughly like this

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

You are already in right direction but I made little changed to `set_current_team` and added accessor method to get current team instance.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_team

  helper_method :current_team

  def set_current_team
    return unless session[:current_team]
    session[:current_team] = current_user.teams.first.id
  end

  def current_team
    @_team ||= Team.find(session[:current_team])
  end
end
```

The `current_team` method uses memoization technique to cache the current team during the request so that if you call `current_team` multiple times during a request, it will not call the DB again to get the team record.

I strongly recommend to read this article [4 Simple Memoization Patterns in Ruby](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem).

Also notice `helper_method` macro above the `set_current_team` which makes this helper method available to your view as well.

so following will work on your index

```
<p><%= current_team %></p>
```

as well as across all controllers as all controllers inherits from `ApplicationController`

Comment: So far this seems to be the best solution. However, I'm getting this as my output for <p><%= current_team %></p>: ```#<Team:0x00007fe5846341a8>``` I should have also told you that I have a join table Team_Members, but I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: It is printing object. Now if you have `name` field in `teams` table, you can print name of current team using `current_team.name`. like wise you can access all the columns/attributes of team object.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `session[:current_team]`, you can save it to a variable in any controller. Say for instance in the teams controller, you can do: `@current_team = session[:current_team]`. Then in the view you can use `@current_team`.

Comment: This is definitely part of where I was going wrong. I didn't realize I had to assign the session cookie value to a variable.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, I'm still getting some kind of Hash output on my view. ```#<Team:0x00007fe58f47b360>```

Comment: What are you using in your view? Are you using <%= @current_team %>?

Answer (score 0):

update `set_current_team` method to

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_current_team

  # only set the session[:current_team] if it is nil (when user login)
  def set_current_team
    session[:current_team] ||= current_user.teams.first.id
  end

  # to access current_team
  def current_team
    @current_team ||= Team.find(session[:current_team])
  end
end
```

set `session[:current_team]` to user selected team id in **controller#action** that handles the request

set `session[:current_team]` to `nil` when user logout